# How do I get the content from an old message/command with my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to edit an embed with a command. The edited embed has a clear structure. It is supposed to be an evaluation of the suggestion. For this I need the author and his suggestion from the previous command. Is it possible to take the content of the old embed and transfer it to the edited embed if you have two commands? In addition, it would be good to still count and insert the reactions at the message.
Here are my working approaches, except for the missing parts:

```py
    #@commands.cooldown(1, 100, BucketType.user)
    @commands.command(usage="<text>")
    async def suggest(self, ctx, *, text: str = None):
        """This is the command for suggestions."""
        if text is None:
            await ctx.send("**You need to insert a text.**")
            return self.suggest.reset_cooldown(ctx)

        channel1 = self.bot.get_channel(812284187427864616)
        if channel1 == ctx.channel:

            channel = self.bot.get_channel(812283430707920906)
                e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.green())
                e.description = f "**__submitter:__**\n {ctx.author}"
                e.add_field(name="__Suggestion:__", value=f"{text}")
                e.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
                e.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
                e.set_footer(text=f "UID: {ctx.author.id}")
                feedback = await channel.send(embed=e)
                await feedback.add_reaction("✅")
                await feedback.add_reaction("❌")
                await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

The approve command which actually edits the old embed and should insert "Suggestion", "Submitter" and count the reactions.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def approve(self, ctx, msg_id: int = None, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
        if not msg_id:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(812283430707920906) # the message's channel
            msg_id = 998877665544332211 # the message's id
        elif not channel:
            channel = ctx.channel
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.title = "Suggestion accepted"
        embed.description = "*Here are all the important information*"
        embed.add_field(name="Results", value="✅: MISSING COUNT / ❌: MISSING COUNT")
        embed.add_field(name="Suggestion", value=f"MISSING SUGGESTION TEXT")
        embed.add_field(name="Submitter:", value=f"MISSING SUBMITTER")
        embed.add_field(name="Approved by:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}")
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        await msg.clear_reactions()
```

To count the reactions I would use something like:

```py
total_count = 0
for r in message.reactions:
    total_count += r.count
```

**EDIT:**
This is the embed right now with showing `Suggestion` two times in different ways.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def approve(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, msgID: int):
        try:
            msg = await channel.fetch_message(msgID)
            embed = msg.embeds[0]
            submitter = embed.description[embed.description.find('\n'):]
            suggestion = embed.fields[0].value

            embed.title = "Suggestion accepted"
            embed.description = "*Here are all the important information*"
            embed.add_field(name="Results", value="✅: Test/ ❌: Test", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Suggestion", value=f"{suggestion}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Submitter", value=f"{submitter}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Approved by", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
            await msg.edit(embed=embed, reference=msgID)
            await msg.clear_reactions()
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)`
You can use the fetched message to get details about it.

```py
try:
   msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
   embed = msg.embeds[0] 
   submitter = embed.description[embed.description.find('/n'):] # get submitter name
   suggestion = embed.fields[0].value
   # other stuff
except:
   pass
   # possible exceptions message not found, list index out of range(if wrong msg id with no embeds passed as arg)
```

References:
[fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
[embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)
[message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)